# Factor the polynomial $z^n-1$ into factors of degree 1. Find the residue at $\frac{1}{z^n-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I was looking for some help on the question of factoring $z^n-1$ into factors of degree 1. 
I found a solution that wrote

$z^n-1 = (z-1)(z-e^{i\theta})(z-e^{i2\theta})...(z-e^{i(n-1)\theta})$ for $\theta = \frac{2\pi}{n}$

But I have no clue how they came to this conclusion! 
Can anyone help with some intuition as to how to solve this or how they came up with this answer?

Answer (score 2):

It follows from [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula) that the roots of $z^n-1$ are $1$, $\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}n\right)$, $\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i}n\right)$, …, $\exp\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi i}n\right)$. So, since $z^n-1$ is a monic polynomial with degree $n$,$$z^n-1=(z-1)\left(z-\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i}n\right)\right)\left(z-\exp\left(\frac{4\pi i}n\right)\right)\cdots\left(z-\exp\left(\frac{2(n-1)\pi i}n\right)\right).$$

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of looking at De Moivre's!

Answer (score 0):

To factor $z^n-1$ into $n$ factors, you need to be in $\mathbb{C}$. There, write $z$ in *polar form*:
$$z = \rho e^{i \theta}$$
where $\rho = |z|$ and $\theta = arg(z)$.
Since $|z|^n = |z^n| = |1|=1$, whe get $\rho=|z|=1$, and the equation becomes :
$$e^{ni\theta} = 1$$
But this amounts to say that $\boxed{n\theta = 0\mod 2\pi}$
In other words, $\theta = \frac{k}{n}2\pi$ for $k\in \mathbb{Z}$. But since $e^{i\theta}=e^{i\theta'}$ whenever $\theta - \theta'\equiv 0 \mod 2\pi$, only
the residue class $\bar{k}\in \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ matters. The representatives of these residue classes are $\theta_k :=\frac{2k\pi}{n}$ for $0\leqslant k < n$.
All in all, you get
$$ z^n = 1 \Longleftrightarrow z= e^{i\theta_k} \textrm{ for }0\leqslant k < n $$

Such a $z$ is called a *root* of the *polynomial* $Z^n-1$. Since we have all roots of the polynomial $Z^n-1$, we can decompose it into :
$$ Z^n-1 = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \big(Z - e^{i\theta_k}\big) $$